# How can I print an integer to the cursor in a Vim function?

Tags: vim

I'm making a simple vim function that counts to `n` in binary (each number on a new line). I just can't figure out the correct function to use. I tried `:put` but that added a new line character every time I used it, which isn't what I want.

Comment: You want a function that upon calling will put a number, from 1 to n, each on its separate line, right? (how do you expect to do that without the newline characters?)

Comment: Can you build up your binary number completely in a register and `:put` the result to the buffer only once? Or could you use the `p` or `gp` commands instead of `:put` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `:normal` command to use any sort of normal mode params. In particular, `:normal i0` will insert a `0`, and `:normal I0` will put a 0 at the beginning of the line.